# How do I count number of visitors on a Django website?

Tags: python, django

How do I count visitors on my website so that it increments every time a user visits the website. I can count number of views by visitors using following codes:

```
def blog_detail(request, blog_slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
    session_key = 'blog_views_{}'.format(blog.slug)
    if not request.session.get(session_key):
        blog.blog_views += 1  # here
        blog.save()
        request.session[session_key] = True

    context = {
        'blog': blog,
        'categories': get_category_count()
    }

    return render(request, 'blogs/blog-detail.html', context)
```

while having `blog_views` field in my models. I don't know if there is any similar way of doing it just to count number of times my website is visited.

Some suggested using `hitcount` but I couldn't use it anywhere other than generic views. If you suggest it as well please elaborate it further with some codes thank you.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the "counting" logic on every view you can write a [middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/) for that. Something like this:

```
def hitcount_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = get_response(request)

        # Get the URL from the `request` parameter and save it 
        # in a Hitcount model.

        return response

    return middleware
```

By doing this,

- all your logic will be in the same place (i.e. easy to mantain),
- the code in your `views` will be cleaner,
- can be enabled/disabled easily,
- can be optimized easily (using Django cache for example).

Hope it helps.

Comment: One small drawback with this approach (doing analytics on the server in general) is that if you want to optimise your site and use external caching or a CDN to serve static parts of your site, you might not see that traffic. But that depends on your caching strategy (if you use django caching your middleware would still be hit and this answer works) of course.

Comment: @dirkgroten Good catch! I've just edited my answer to clarify Django cache.

Comment: @ Cartucho Thank you very much for your anwser! I found this aproach interesting but, i'm struggling to find the right logic to count the visits, shoukd i make an entry on the database and add for each visit then make it appear on the django admin? any pointers would be greatly aprecciated, good night!

Answer (score 3):

Unsure if your question remains, but there are few projects that might help you.
There's [Django-visits](https://pypi.org/project/django-visits/) that count requested urls (CounterMiddleware) or count object visits.

```py
from visits.models import Visits

def some_object_view(request, pk):
    some_obj = get_object_or_404(SOME_MODEL, pk=pk)
    Visit.objects.add_object_visit(request, obj=some_obj)
```

There's also the [django-hitcount](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#models) project that enables several options to count hits on pages or objects.

```py
from django.db import models

from hitcount.models import HitCountMixin

# here is an example model with a GenericRelation
class MyModel(models.Model, HitCountMixin):

  # adding a generic relationship makes sorting by Hits possible:
  # MyModel.objects.order_by("hit_count_generic__hits")
  hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
    HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
    related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')

# you would access your hit_count like so:
my_model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
my_model.hit_count.hits                 # total number of hits
my_model.hit_count.hits_in_last(days=7) # number of hits in last seven days
```

Comment: please add code samples in case those links expire.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that the code samples would help in case links expire, but I'm not sure how to add samples in those specific cases. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You can check packages https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/analytics/

Or

Use [google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) instead writing the logic in django app. Google Analytics is free to use.

Answer (score 0):

*Add below code in view function and home.html template page*

## views.py

```
 def HOME(request):
    "#Number of visits to this view, as counted in the session variable."
    num_visits = request.session.get('num_visits', 0)
    request.session['num_visits'] = num_visits + 1
    context = {'num_visits': num_visits
    }
    return render(request,'home.html',context=context)
```

### home.html

```
Visitors Count {{ num_visits }}
```

This will give count on the mail home page whenever it is refreshed.