# How do I get the number of visitors currently looking at my django website?

Tags: python, django

I need to find the number of active visitors in my website and display it. Django version is 3.0

Comment: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493511/how-do-i-count-number-of-visitors-on-a-django-website) For Answer for your query #python #django

Answer (score 0):

Standard HTTP servers send information to browsers when the browser requests something, so your server wouldn't actually have a count of people currently viewing the site (unless your using Django Channels?).

What you could do is a metric along the lines of active users in the last 5 minutes. Make a model that stores a datetime(auto_now=True) and an ip and then implement some middleware to create instances of this model.

```
def hitcount_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

        record = VisitorRecord.objects.get_or_create(ip=ip)
        record.save() # This is necessary for updating datetime.

        return response

    return middleware
```

Then in your view. Select all records within the last 5 minutes and display the .count()

Comment: This will only track _logged in_ users. For all other users `request.user` will be an instance of `AnonymousUser`, and the `get_or_create()` will simply update the same record over and over again. The count of anonymous users will therefore always be `1`.

Comment: Good point well made. Have adjusted my answer to use IP instead.

Comment: That is an improvement, but still flawed. IP addresses do not identify unique users. Organisation often have the same external IP address for every user inside the organization. To determine the actual number of unique, active visitors your middleware will have to place a tracking cookie on the computer of the user _and_ calculate some metric for "activity", after they have given consent of course.

Comment: You could store the activity metric inside `request.session` to let Django handle that tracking cookie automatically.

Comment: Use the CSRF token instead of IP then